# Android How to disabled predictive text programatically in samsung tab 2

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

My code is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA Code I Use.

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

I use **android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|text"** in EditText its disabled predictive text for all devices but in **Samsung Tab 2** it's not working. 
I also apply through android code but seems its open give any other suggestions for disabled this predictive text box in **Samsung Tab 2.**

[image: Other Device Image]

Other device preview it's not showing predictive text box.

[image: Samsung Tab 2 Image]

Samsung Tab 2 preview it's showing predictive text box.

Answer (score 6):

i have also same problem is once upon time and i am find solution change edittext input type as `textVisiblePassword` like mention below xml layout

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:textSize="22dp" />
```

It's will works on samsung tab2 on following code
 `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`