# Disable soft keyboard predictive text for WebView in KitKat

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-softkeyboard, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a textarea in a `WebView`. I need to have the predictive text disabled when the soft keyboard appears. So this is what I'm doing.

```
<textarea autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />
```

This works perfectly except in KitKat. Are these attributes broken in the new WebView in KitKat? What are the alternatives?

Comment: I know [this is hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17419024/1777090), but check if that works

Comment: @PurpleDroid I'm using a `WebView`. The linked post uses an `EditText`.

Comment: @ShubhadeepChaudhuri do you remember when did you add this `<textarea /> ` tag? May I know if you have found the solution to this issue?